# How to access current solution after an iteration of the Barrier algorithm?

Tags: c++, callback, cplex

I want to access the current solution of QP after an iteration of the Barrier algorithm. There is a callback *ContinuousCallbackI* that is triggered after each iteration.
I modified the callback code example:

```
static ILOBARRIERCALLBACK2(MyCallback, IloCplex, cplex, IloNumVarArray, x) {
    cout << "Iteration " << getNiterations() << ": ";

    if (isFeasible()) {
        cout << "Objective = " << getObjValue() << endl;
        //cout << "x[0] = " << (float)cplex.getValue(x[0]) << endl; 
        //CPLEX Error  1217: No solution exists.
    }
    else {
        cout << "Infeasibility measure = " << getInfeasibility() << endl;
    }
}
```

But cplex doesn't have a solution (error). Is there any way to access the current solution after an iteration?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access the current solution.

From inside a callback, only member functions of the callback class should be invoked.  These member functions are listed at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refcppopl/html/classes/IloCplex_BarrierCallbackI.html, and there is not one that allows to query the current solution.